# There is no tap effect for custom UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

When I am initializing UIButton,I can provide it's type in it's init. However, I can't give it a type if I am using custom button because the buttonType property is get-only and I can't put it in the init function as well.

```
class Button: UIButton {
    init(placeholder: String) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        setTitle(placeholder, for: .normal)
        setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 0.3647058904, green: 0.06666667014, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1).withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        layer.cornerRadius = 5
        setHeight(50)
        titleLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can't call `convenience init(type buttonType: UIButton.ButtonType)` from the init method of your subclass (because subclass must call a designated initializer of the superclass) but you could implement following method that creates your button with system type:

```
class Button: UIButton {
    static func systemButton(placeholder: String) -> Button {
        let button = Button(type: .system)
        button.setTitle(placeholder, for: .normal)
        // ...
        return button
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly. However, I have a question: If my only purpose is setting these properties and nothing at all for creating custom button, the way I should do is like this or should I make an extension to the UIButton for this ?
1- ```private let loginButton = AuthenticationButton.authButton(placeholder: "Log In") ```
2- ```private let loginButton2: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.authButton(placeholder: "Log In")
    return button
}()```

Comment: You can go both ways. I would probably create a method in an extension without subclassing but both is ok.